# Import data from CSV into MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to import data from a CSV file into MySQL using php. I have run this code and I am not sure why it does not record the information. I have tested out my commend $q and it is working in phpadmin.

I keep getting the error message "Import is not successful"

Would you mind have a look and tell me where I went wrong?
Thank you.

```
<?php

class csv extends mysqli
{
    private $state_CSV = false; //Validate the status of the CSV file

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("localhost","root","*******","db");
        if ($this->connect_error) {
            echo "Fail to connect to Database : ". $this->connect_error;
        }
    }


    //import file in to read all data one by one
    public function import ($file)
    {
      if (($file = fopen ($file,'r')) !==FALSE) //r = read
      {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file,1000,",")) !== FALSE) {

                //process data from each column 
                $serial = $row[1] ;
                $status = $row[2];
                $title = $row[3];
                $category = $row[4];
                $synopsis = $row[5];


                //Insert value into the database
                $q = "  INSERT INTO movie (title,synopsis,category) 
                        VALUES ('$title','$synopsis','$category');

                        INSERT INTO inventory (serialnumber,status,movie_id)
                        VALUES ('$serial','$status',LAST_INSERT_ID())

                     ";

                    //echo $q;      //open here to show what the query look like

                echo $q;

                if ( $this->query($q)){
                    $this->state_CSV = true;    // function will now return the ID instead of true.



                }else{
                    $this->state_CSV = false;
                    echo "<br/>error INSERT ". $title. "<br/>"; //if is not run perfectly
                }

            }
                //showing notification, problem 

                if ($this->state_CSV) {
                echo "Your data has been successfully imported";
                }else{
                //echo "Something went wrong while importing your data";
                echo "<br/> <br/> Import is not successful";
            }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: you are effectively running multiple queries ( or not as the case may be ) - the `query` method of `mysqli` cannot, afaik, handle multiple sql statements like that - perhaps https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php might be of interest?

Comment: So how have you got to this from yesterdays question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61474888/get-id-from-previous-insert-and-use-as-a-reference-record-for-another-table-php?

Comment: That code looks vulnerable to SQL injection - please check whether you could use prepared statements